# how to get order details based on multiple user of single item laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$users = User::where('parent_id', $user_id)
                ->get()
                ->toArray();

$query = Order::where('item_ids' , $item_id);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($users); $i++) {

    $query->where(function($q) use ($users, $i) {
        $q->where('user_id', $users[$i]);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

}
```

How can I get all users based on `item_id`?.

I tried above code which doesn't work. Please guide.

How to get order details based on multiple user of single item?

Comment: What does `item_ids` have? Single Id or Multiple Id's?

Comment: item_ids has single id users id are multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for loop slows down the processing you can use laravel query builder such as where

for more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

```
$users = User::where('parent_id', $user_id)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
    $query = Order::where('item_ids' , $item_id)->whereIn('user_id', $users)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Grammar::parameterize
() must be of the type array, integer given, called in \/var\/www\//vendor
\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Query\/Grammars\/Grammar.php on line 311 and defined"
,"file":"\/var\/www\/html/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database
\/Grammar.php","line":108}}

Comment: add toArray() next to the users query

Comment: {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member
 function toArray() on a non-object","file":

Comment: check if parent exists with that id because it might be returning you null with that $user_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164592/discussion-between-rohit-shah-and-alax).

Answer (score 0):

Use `pluck()` to get all user ids and `whereIn()` to fetch the all matching record :

```
$users = User::where('parent_id', $user_id)->pluck('id');
    $query = Order::where('item_ids' , $item_id)->whereIn('user_id', $users)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```